# How to avoid misformatting of binary values with GNU indent?

Tags: gnu, indentation

When GNU indent (at least version 2.2.6 and 2.2.10) is used on the following code...

```
void
main ()
{
  int i = 0b01010101;
}
```

it will be reformatted into this ...

```
void
main ()
{
  int i = 0 b01010101;
}
```

Is there any option in indent that avoids this behavior?

Comment: I reproduced the same behavior on BSD indent that comes with Mac OS X 10.5. Are you sure it's GNU indent you have problems with? If it is, at least you have some idea where to report the bug. I'll file it in Radar but I really don't know why I bother...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer to this question on the indent mailing list:

> No intent doesn't support C derivatives: that construct isn't C.

The [Binary constants using the `0b' prefix](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) is just an extension of gcc.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

indent | sed -r 's/(0) (b[01]+)/\1\2/g'
```